# Issue where EF Core migration succeeded but database was not created

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to do EF Core migration but the database was not created and there was no error message.

I would really appreciate it if someone could enlighten me to solve this issue. I tried to create a SQL Server database using SSMS manually, it was successful. So, there was no problem with my SQL Server.

This is what I did in VS Code terminal

```
dotnet ef migrations add "SqlServer Initial" -p Infrastructure -s API -c StoreContext -o Data/Migrations
```

> Build started...
> Build succeeded.
>
> info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
> Entity Framework Core 3.1.6 initialized 'StoreContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
> Done. To undo this action, use 'ef migrations remove'

This is what I have in my `.csproj` file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Core\Core.csproj"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.6"/>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.1.6"/>
      <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis" Version="2.1.58"/>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0"/>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore"     Version="3.1.6"/>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="6.7.1"/>
      <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.7.1"/>
      <PackageReference Include="Stripe.net" Version="39.16.0"/>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.0"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you then run:
dotnet ef database update

Comment: What you posted creates a new migration, it doesn't deploy it. How did you try to deploy the database? What was the exact command? Did you target the correct database?